# Enquiry on literature on level of alcohol consumption associated with onset of Alcohol Use Disorder

Tags: epidemiology, alcoholism

The literature on the relative risks of mortality (all cause and cardiovascular) of different levels (volumes) of alcohol use or consumption (operationalised here in terms of Quantity-Frequency measure (e.g. grams per day)) is numerous.[1-2]

However, to my knowledge, there does not seem to be much literature on the relative risks of onset of Alcohol Use Disorder (AUD) by level of alcohol use.

Tuithof describes the proportions (12month prevalence) of those with 'High average alcohol consumption' who have AUD[3], in a cross sectional study. This unfortunately does not quite address the requirement of this question.

Also, Rehm has modelled the percentages of the US population who have AUD by the level of alcohol use[4]. As it does model '0'/zero volume drinking, and its the percentage with AUD at that level is reported in the figure as zero %., one can see that the proportions with AUD increase at any level of consumption after that. I was wondering whether there might be any other literature that also reports this. Especially if they are based on cohort study data (as opposed to the cross sectional survey data underlying Rehm's model).

As such, I would be grateful if there might be leads to any literature that can inform of the level of alcohol use at which the risk of the onset of AUD exceeds that of a comparator population.

Thank you.

notes:
[1] Stockwell, T., et al (2016). Do “Moderate” Drinkers Have Reduced Mortality Risk? A Systematic Review and Meta-Analysis of Alcohol Consumption and All-Cause Mortality. Journal of Studies on Alcohol and Drugs, 77(2), 185–198. https://doi.org/10.15288/jsad.2016.77.185
[2] Jayasekara, H., et al (2014). Alcohol consumption over time and risk of death: A systematic review and meta-analysis. American Journal of Epidemiology. Oxford University Press. https://doi.org/10.1093/aje/kwu028
[3] Tuithof, M., et al (2014). The Relationship Between Excessive Alcohol Consumption and Alcohol Use Disorders According to DSM-IV and DSM-5. Alcoholism: Clinical and Experimental Research, 38(1), 249–256. https://doi.org/10.1111/acer.12248
[4] Rehm, J. T., Room, R., & Taylor, B. (2008). Method for moderation: Measuring lifetime risk of alcohol-attributable mortality as a basis for drinking guidelines. International Journal of Methods in Psychiatric Research, 17(3), 141–151. https://doi.org/10.1002/mpr.259

Comment: [NIAAA](https://www.niaaa.nih.gov/alcohol-health/overview-alcohol-consumption/moderate-binge-drinking) defines binge drinking as a pattern of drinking that brings blood alcohol concentration (BAC) levels to 0.08 g/dL in 2 hours. This typically occurs after 4 drinks for women and 5 drinks for men.